# update relationship property if previous relationship exists in NEO4J

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to construct a query in cypher that does the following:

- create a relationship between 2 nodes with a property containing a time duration if no relationship exists already
- if a relationship is already present, update the time duration property
  to be the shortest duration of the two relationships

The compare and update part is something that I am not able to achieve in cypher. So any assistence on this part is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need combine [`MERGE ON CREATE | ON MATCH`](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/merge/#_use_on_create_and_on_match) and [`CASE expression`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/expressions/#query-syntax-case). For example:

```
MATCH (A:City {id: 1})
MATCH (B:City {id: 2})
WITH A, B, toInteger(rand()*100) as newDuration
MERGE (A)-[r:next]->(B)
  ON CREATE SET r.duration = newDuration
  ON MATCH  SET r.duration = CASE 
                                 WHEN r.duration > newDuration 
                                 THEN newDuration 
                                 ELSE r.duration 
                             END
RETURN r.duration
```