# How to conditionally add property to relationship from CSV in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I am making a Neo4j graph to show a network of music artists.

I have a CSV with a few columns. The first column is called `Artist` and is the person who made the song. The second and third columns are called `Feature1` and `Feature2`, respectively, and represent the featured artists on a song (see example https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TE8MtNy6XnR2_QE_0W8iwoWVifd6b7KXl20oCTVo5Ug/edit?usp=sharing)

I have merged so that any given artist has just a single node. Artists are connected by a `FEATURED` relationship with a `strength` property that represents the number of times someone has been featured. When the relationship is initialized, the relationship property strength is set to 1. For example, when `(X)-[r:FEATURED]->(Y)` occurs the first time `r.strength = 1`.

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (a:artist) ASSERT a.artistName IS UNIQUE;
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (f:feature) ASSERT f.artistName IS UNIQUE;
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (f:feature1) ASSERT f.artistName IS UNIQUE;

USING PERIODIC COMMIT
    LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS from 'aws/artist-test.csv' as line
MERGE (artist:Artist {artistName: line.Artist})
MERGE (feature:Artist {artistName: line.Feature1})
MERGE (feature1:Artist {artistName: line.Feature2})
CREATE (artist)-[:FEATURES {strength:1}]->(feature)
CREATE (artist)-[:FEATURES {strength:1}]->(feature1)
```

Then I deleted the None node for songs that have no features

```
MATCH (artist:Artist {artistName:'None'})
OPTIONAL MATCH (artist)-[r]-() 
DELETE artist, r
```

If X features Y on another song further down the CSV, the code currently creates another (duplicate) relationship with `r.strength = 1`. Rather than creating a new relationship, I'd like to have only the one (previously created) relationship and increase the value of `r.strength` by 1.

Any idea how can I do this? My current approach has been to just create a bunch of duplicate relationships, then go back through and count all duplicate relationships, and set 
`r.strength = #duplicate relationships`. However, I haven't been able to get this to work, and before I waste more time on this, I figured there is a more efficient way to accomplish this.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42716898/update-relationship-property-if-previous-relationship-exists-in-neo4j). See if it helps.

Comment: By the way: none of your `CREATE CONSTRAINT` clauses do anything for you, since you do not use `artist`, `feature`, and `feature1` as node labels. You should use this instead: `CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (a:Artist) ASSERT a.artistName IS UNIQUE;`. Also, the property name `artistName` is a bit redundant for `Artist` nodes; you may want to use the simpler `name` instead.

Comment: Okay, makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use MERGE on relationships with ON MATCH SET

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
    LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS from 'aws/artist-test.csv' as line
MERGE (artist:Artist {artistName: line.Artist})
MERGE (feature:Artist {artistName: line.Feature1})
MERGE (feature1:Artist {artistName: line.Feature2})

MERGE (artist)-[f1:FEATURES]->(feature) 
ON CREATE SET f1.strength = 1
ON MATCH SET f2.strength = f1.strength + 1

MERGE (artist)-[f2:FEATURES]->(feature1) 
ON CREATE SET f2.strength = 1
ON MATCH SET f2.strength = f2.strength + 1
```